# Subsequence definition

Tags: analysis

I am a little lost about why subsequences necessarily converge to the same limit as their respective sequence. Consider a sequence where S:N$\rightarrow$Q$\in$[0,3], where the naturals are mapped to every rational in order in the interval. By the definition of convergence, S$\rightarrow$3.
Now consider the sequence where you remove all the elements of S$\in$(2,3]. This creates a new sequence B:N$\rightarrow$Q$\in$[0,2]. B$\rightarrow$2
Why is B not a subsequence of S? Is there no way to do what I am describing and maintain the order of S? If so why?

Comment: " the naturals are mapped to every rational in order in the interval". This can't be done. What do you think $2$ would get mapped to? And while I don't understand your construction well enough to know if that's an essential part of it, you should probably fix that first.

Comment: I agree with JohnathanZ. If by S:N$\rightarrow$Q$\in$[0,3] you meant, $S:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,3]$ and $S$ is surjective, then $S$ cannot be a convergent sequence. I'm guessing there are deeper conceptual issues here than just notation, although it might not take forever to address each one.

Comment: Maybe $a_n = 3 - 1/n$ would work for your initial sequence? My guess is that there is a basic misunderstanding of exactly what a subsequence is, and how to define one. Perhaps using this $a_n$ as a starting point could help us figure out how you're thinking about them?

Comment: The example that you give doesn't exist, an even if it existed, is not a counterexample, so we have two problems here. First, there is no order-preserving bijection of the naturals and the rationals. Secondly, I think you are mixing the direction of the implication. You say: $(x_n)\rightarrow x$ implies that any subsequence of $(x_n)$ also converges to $x$, which is absolutely correct, but your counterexample would show that you have a sequence with converging subsequences to different limits. This is the opposite implication, which is in general false, so wouldn't contradict anything.

Comment: @Will I think you have pinned down your error. Since between the rationals $a$ and $b$ there lies the rational $\frac{a+b}{2}$ there can be no "next" rational.

Answer (score 0):

Even if such a sequence were to exist, that would not be a subsequence: which can be seen by the fact that:

S-->3 $\implies$ $\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t $ n>N$ $\implies |x_n-3|<\epsilon $ , so taking the contrapositive : $|x_n-3|\geq\epsilon \implies n\leq N $.

So there would only be a finite number of terms less than or equal to two. So any subsequence we took would be finite. But that's not possible, a subsequence should be infinite.

But this assumption is not correct obviously, you can't construct such a mapping.

@JonathanZ's example is a good example to see if you can understand subsequences as you can have a finite number of terms less than 2 in that one! If I took only the terms $\leq$ 2, then I get only one term , and that's clearly not a subsequence!

Comment: Why can't you map the naturals to an interval of rationals in order if they are the same size?

Comment: The issue is that they have to be ordered, I can always just find the midpoint of two rationals , and that should be between those two terms in the sequence! So that would happen forever, and I can't construct such a sequence.

Comment: That makes sense thank you

Comment: @Will your question is the same as this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/330846/homeomorphism-between-rationals-and-natural-numbers "Homemorphic" means "continuous mapping between the two sets", and so the linked question is the same question as the one you asked in your previous comment.